# Admob not crawling app-ads.txt even after 10 days of adding developer website in store listing

Tags: admob, google-crawlers, app-ads.txt

I have added app-ads.txt with the help of https://www.app-ads-txt.com/ website.
But even after 10 days, i don't see any update in admob dashboard (no crawler crawled yet).
What might be the issue?

Comment: please refer to this website https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9363762?hl=en

Comment: For AdMob to find and verify your app-ads.txt file, be aware of the following:

    Your app must be registered with Google Play or the Apple App Store.
    The store listing for your app must include a developer website

Comment: @AmodGokhale yes, i already included that everywhere in developer console. In support section (contact details) as well as developer website. But, still i see the same.

Comment: try this troubleshooting https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9776740

Comment: No, it's the same even after several months. And i finally stopped waiting for it, and started focussing on my other works

Comment: Google says "The crawl is based on the developer website in your app store listing.". Must this be the "Support URL" or the "Marketing URL"? I do not have a "Marketing URL" yet so I think this might be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after several days of adding app-ads.txt. It worked after I updated my app in the store.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, steps I did to get it working:

- add payment method
- verify your account (setup of payment method needed, but you do not have to enter any actual payment details, such as a bank account yet)

Your apps should be verified and "Ready" after 24 hrs. However, the crawler only found my apps-ads.txt AFTER I have implemented admob banners and pushed the change into the app stores. I believe the crawler only starts "crawling" if there is actual ad traffic - but that's just a guess. Google also states somewhere, that the crawler might need up to one month to find ads-txt, if your app has low traffic.

Comment: **I believe the crawler only starts "crawling" if there is actual ad traffic - but that's just a guess.** This seems meaningful to me